# Play Store says "This app is not compatible with any of your devices"

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, android-market-filtering

I know this has been asked time and again, but most questions and answers are years old and I have not yet seen any solutions that work, or any real explanations for that matter.

I have an [app on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.magnuswikhog.adrdangerousgoods) which has been working fine the past four years. Today I went to Google Play Store on my computer and was terrified when I saw that it says "This app is not compatible with any of your devices"! Clicking the "Buy" button showed me a dialog where all my devices where gray and it showed me that the permissions of my app included that it could access media, photos, etc.

I removed the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission (this breaks a tiny feature which is extremely seldom used by the average user) and uploaded it again. When the new version was available it **still** said that it is incompatible with all my devices! Although now when I click "Buy" it just says that the app doesn't require any particular permissions (it still requires ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, INTERNET and CHECK_LICENSE though).

Even stranger is when I look at the app in the Google Play Store app on a device, it says nothing about it being incompatible. I have not seen any dramatic decline in new users either, so I have hope that it's "just" something wrong with Google Play detecting that I'm logged in to the developers account while visiting the Play Store. Even so, it's a very confusing error message!

Has anyone else experienced this and been able to resolve it? Should I be worried? Should I contact Google (like they'll actually read any feedback)?

At this point I'm just happy it doesn't seem to affect my app sales, but either way I would like to know the cause of the problem.

My registered devices on Google Play include a Samsung Galaxy S5, Google Nexus One, Motorola Moto G and Lenovo A7600 Tablet.

Comment: There's a link in the text that'll take you straight to it. Read again.

Comment: I would say send an email out to google, regardless of their lack of/slow responsiveness. That does sound strange. The app looks OK from my end.

Comment: Are you login in the web browser with any google account that does't have a compatible device registered with that account?

Comment: No problem here, it's compatible with Nexus 6P, Nexus 5, a few kind of Samsung Galaxy phones and a few others.

Comment: Alright thanks guys, have contacted Google through the support page and explained the problem. If I get any response I'll update this question (if it's not closed by then). Hoping it's "just" a glitch in Google Play on desktop...

Comment: @belen No all my devices listed as incompatible are in definitely compatible. I'm developing on some of them. In fact, in the Dev Console it says 11565 compatible devices, 0 incompatible. (no, I don't own 11565 devices, I guess that's all the Android devices available out there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I contacted Google Play Developer Support and got the following answer:

> You will receive an error message when you try to purchase your own application. If you are signed in with the primary email address of the Developer Account for the application, you will see the "incompatible" message.

So I guess it's expected behaviour, although I can't remember seeing the "incompatible" message before. IMHO they should come up with a less confusing way of telling me I can't purchase my own app.